# When you vote to close a question, are you subscribed to the question?

Tags: discussion, questions, moderation

When you vote to close a question, are you subscribed to the question? I was going to suggest a feature that automatically posts a "voting to close" comment on a question when the vote is cast so people can ask questions that get sent to the notifications feed of the voter. But then I realized this might already, in effect, happen.

Either way, it took me a while to figure out what to do with silent closure votes. I still find it unintuitive and, if anyone else shares this experience, I think a box under the question would be helpful if it tells the user how to proceed before more votes are cast. Something like "_____ has voted to close this question. Comment on this question to ask him/her why before the question reaches five closure votes." would help.

Comment: No, and notifications to close voters has been suggested before and rejected (and if I remember correctly, the request was heavily downvoted), we really _don't_ want to give people the option of hassling close voters.

Comment: I believe you are misunderstanding the purpose of "closing" a question. You speak here and in other questions of people having a "chance to fix" a post, before it is closed. In fact, *being closed is that chance* to fix the post. Then it can be flagged for reopening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you do not get notified of comments when you vote to close, unless you are specifically @mentioned.

Apparently moderators do get notified of comments after having voted to close though. Poor sods.

Also, note that you do not get to *see* closing votes until you've reached at least [250 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-close-votes).

Comment: There's an exception for moderators, we do get notified if we voted to close. Unfortunately.

Comment: @YannisRizos: Thanks, that's interesting (and I do not envy you then, or at least a little less now that I know that)!

Comment: @YannisRizos Would it make an impact on notification flooding if you were only notified of direct responses to your vote, and of edits to the question, instead of all activity regarding the question and its answers?

Comment: @Jordan - No, and it is not necessary. If a question is closed by 5 people, there are more than 10.000 other user who can vote to reopen. You don't have to get in contact with the original voters.