# Rolling Back Approved Edits

Tags: support, edits, review, suggested-edits, rollbacks

I have looked for this particular question and cannot find it, but have a suspicion, it may be a duplicate.

I reviews [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2582405).
I went to reject it as

> invalid edit
>
> This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or  comment on the
>   existing post.

And got this error message:

[image: Error msge]

I then went to [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17852234/revisions) on StackOverflow. Rolledback the edit and left a comment.

[image]

*As, usual, whenever I use an example for a question on this site, something out of the ordinary happens to the post, so I can only laugh, when you see the revision made since.. However, Murphy's law aside.*

**What is the best way to deal with an approved edit, you don't believe is correct?**

Comment: On that specific case the OP himself approved the edit so there was no need to roll back, it was typo and didn't affect the actual question. Generally speaking, rolling back is legit when you feel the edit changed too much but use `@` to notify the editor otherwise small chance he'll notice the comment.

Comment: OH, I didn't think to look if it was the OP who approved it, my bad.. oh, this is a REALLY BAD  example

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd How can I see who approved the edit?

Comment: @Skippy [the edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2582405) you linked above has it.  All votes (accept or reject) on the edit are listed.  If you noticed one of the approvers has a blue background, that's the OP.

Comment: Err, I don't think it matters that the OP is the one who approved the edit. They probably didn't understand that it could obscure a problem with their code. The improvement *looks* like an innocuous correction of a typo and formatting fix, but **it actually removes a semicolon**. That's a pretty big change in languages where semicolons are statement terminators.

Comment: @Cody that semicolon was part of pseudo code: `myclass.foo is equal to some other classes in this list` - that's not actual code so no different than removing a semicolon in a comment.

Comment: @CodyGray I couldn't agree more!! that's why I rolled it back, a semi-colon makes a huge difference, the capitalisation of Foreach was another thing.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. I guess it is pseudo-code. I just assumed it was a language I didn't know! I secretly think all programming languages should aspire to read more like English.

Comment: @CodyGray well, if one thinks it's code, then I guess one can only act as if it IS code.. some code that has been posted as code, does not only make poor code, but porr pseudo code!

Comment: Worth to mention the post was fixed by now and comments are proper comments while code is proper code now.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd have you noticed, most of the examples I use end up having an optimal outcome, which actually makes my question redundant for that example?? I am sure it's Murphy's Law hahahahaha

Comment: @Skippy nah, in this case the fix was made before you posted here and there's no impact on the question, maybe just extra upvote to Daniel as result of the attention here. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd If I had of asked this question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190297/why-are-editors-not-suggested-as-targets-of-comments first, this question above, would've been neater ;) anyway, I better go off this site, while I'm getting along with everyone (Iknow, I know, I am my own worst enemy ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have looked for this particular question and cannot find it, but have a suspicion, it may be a duplicate.
>   …
>   What is the best way to deal with an approved edit, you don't believe is correct?

Well, it's probably not a duplicate, since the answer already appears in the error message you got: "please visit the post and correct the edit".

There are two ways of doing this:

1. Editing the current revision of the post, effectively "improving" the suggested edit.
2. Rolling back the erroneously approved edit.

Using [`@` comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/153008) to notify the user who suggested the edit is also a good practice ([editors of a post are valid targets of comment replies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36052/allow-post-editor-to-see-comments-directed-at-him/36055#36055)), as otherwise [it's very unlikely that they'll be made aware of](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor?rq=1) and learn from their mistakes. The comment you made is fine, you just need to direct it at the person who suggested the edit you reverted.

As for the more general question that you're implicitly asking about when is it appropriate to edit other people's code, that has been discussed before several times here. There's no hard rule, but I have a couple of guidelines:

1. For *questions*, never make any edits to code that are not strictly formatting-related. That includes indenting code blocks, wrapping in backticks, fixing indentation, and removing empty lines. Everything else is off-limits, as it can obscure problems that the answers may need/want to address.
2. For *answers*, you can feel a bit more free to fix typos and other *obvious* errors. But don't make major edits to the code (even if the original doesn't "work" and you're "fixing" it) that deviate from the author's original intent. Leave these suggestions as comments instead.

Comment: leaving an @ for the user who made the suggested edit, doesn't work if they have not made a comment, I agree with you on that

Comment: @Skippy Sure it does. Editors of a post are valid targets of an `@` comment reply. That's documented in the post I linked (which also links to [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36052/allow-post-editor-to-see-comments-directed-at-him/36055#36055)).

Comment: Yes I understand this has been discussed, I guess the issue is, also letting the user know not to make such suggested edits, @cody whan I try to do that the editor's name doesn't come up, does it still notify them if their name doesn't pop up?

Comment: @Skippy Cody it right, `@` will reach even users who closed a question.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd you know how a pop up box appears when you start typing after the @ ? If that user's name does not appear, are they still notifiied if you manually type in their user name?

Comment: Ah, yes. They are, assuming that they fall into one of these categories: the author of the post, anyone with an active bounty on the question, anyone who has left a still-visible comment on the post, and anyone who has edited the post. The suggestion window doesn't show all of those people.

Comment: @CodyGray thank you for that.. could you please answer this (if you think it's Ok to) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190297/tagging-a-user-in-comments-with-with-no-popup don't worry, Bart answered

Comment: @Cody I believe "anyone who cast a close vote" also apply.

Comment: @Sha I don't think so. I believe only diamond moderators who have voted to close are valid targets. I'll hunt down the question if you like, I believe this was changed recently after complaints by frequent close voters about the volume and whinyness of these comments.

Comment: @Cody mind if we'll perform a live test? (one of us will cast a close vote on one of the other's old questions and the other will try to `@comment`)

Comment: @Sha You'd have to *close* the question first. There's no way someone would know who to reply to if only one vote was cast. I found [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142521/when-you-vote-to-close-a-question-are-you-subscribed-to-the-question), but Yannis's comment suggests there are other dupes I'm not finding.

Comment: @Cody we know now, don't we? :)

Answer (score 4):

The OP has accepted the Suggested edit. So, there is no need to rollback.

**What is the best way to deal with an approved edit, you don't believe is correct?**

> You can comment on the post to the OP for rollback the edit. In this
>   case, it doesn't need anything. Leave as it is.

Comment: Azik you are addressing one question, which may have been a poor example (yes it is), it doesn't address what is being asked, if it is altered and shouldn't have been, what does one do.

Comment: @Skippy, you can visit the post and correct the edit as you have enough rep to edit on any post :)

Comment: maybe I am not understanding you.. sorry