# Why are editors not suggested as targets of @ comments?

Tags: feature-request, comments, users, comment-replies

When replying to a user in a comment, their name is automatically suggested in a pop-up:

[image]

But that only works if they have already left a comment.

Sometimes I want to notify a user who has made a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2582405), but there no pop-up that suggests the name of these users:

[image]

Does the user still get a notification of the comment if you manually type in their username?

**Edit**
*I have changed this to a feature request, instead of posting a new question. Is this OK?*

Comment: Sure it's OK to ask but it was already asked before, and declined.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd hahahha converted one dup into another OMG

Comment: I know, Meta is pretty much full by now it's just matter of wading through the requests. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question:

> Does the user still get a notification of the comment if you manually type in their username?

Yes they will. There is just no auto-suggestion for the usernames. See also ["How do comment @replies work"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) for details on which users can receive such @replies.

Comment: Thanks @Bart, This is one of three questions, that serve to answer one series of questions, I didn't want to post them all in one question, so divided them up, Is this the best thing to do??

Comment: I promise, I did search these questions, I found a similar one with no answer

Comment: If they are very closely related, you could keep them in a single question @Skippy. But generally it's indeed better to split them up.

Comment: He knows this already, we hashed it out [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190293/153008). I *think* he's actually intending this to be a [feature-request]: *why* aren't *all* of the candidates auto-suggested?

Comment: @CodyGray It was me making the faulty assumption that they wouldn't be notified

Comment: "She", if I'm not mistaken @CodyGray. But well, perhaps it's useful to others in the future.

Comment: Well, it makes a difference whether I should vote to close as a duplicate. :-)

Comment: @Bart should I turn this into a feature request?? Can I retag it now??

Comment: @Skippy If it isn't aksked before I would upvote the feature request.

Comment: @PeeHaa I made it a feauter request