# Why can't I response to user who edited my answer/question using @reply syntax?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-replies

Quite simple question: Why **can't** I respond to a user who edited my answer/question using @reply syntax?

Comment: If you were considering a feature request: [Expand the username auto-completion to everyone who can be notified](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106534) and [Why are editors not suggested as targets of @ comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190297)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You **can** respond to a user who edited your post using the `@reply` syntax. Quoting from [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work):

> Notifications apply to the author, users with active bounties, commenters (associated to current non-deleted comments), and **editors** of the question or answer that you are commenting on

Emphasis mine.

It just doesn't include their name in the auto-completion box, that is all. The same FAQ page states:

> Tab name completion can be used, and that knows when `@name` is unnecessary and will then not automatically complete names. It also does not work for editors.

Comment: OK, any reason why it's not included in auto-completion?

Comment: To not clutter the autocompletion list? It is rarely needed and mostly would confuse matters. *Wait, what? Who is this Martijn dude?! Oh, he edited my post at some point*.

Comment: Probably also because we want to discourage people from doing this in the majority of cases. It would just get abused for things like `@MartijnPieters Y U DOWNVOTE ME & CLOSE MY QUESTION??!` if Martijn was one of the kind souls who tried to edit the question into shape.