# Is it OK to react in a comment to edits of answers or questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, edits

Sometimes, you want to react to an edit of an answer/question. Is it OK to do this in the comments?

And why is there not an feature to react to edits?

Comment: What do you mean by "react to an edit"?

Comment: ..."this answer" - **which** answer?

Comment: see also: [Why are editors not suggested as targets of @ comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190297/why-are-editors-not-suggested-as-targets-of-comments)